# Thor Not Using the Correct Ruby Version with Shell Commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, zsh, thor

I have a rails project using ruby 2.3.1. OSX has 1.9.3 but I'm using rvm to manage rubies. The rails project has 2.3.1 specified in the gemfile and a .ruby-version dot-file.

Here's the problem: I am converting a rake task to a thor script. It performs some shell commands (specifically `pg_dump` -- I've tried others though) but finds the OSX ruby instead of the one the project uses.

I've tried running the script wrapped with `bundle exec`, and changing the ways I call out to the shell (backticks, `run`, and `system`) and no matter what is done, the following error is issued in stdout:

`Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1`

I must have missed something in the documentation.

Comment: An earlier draft included direnv and zsh as possible players, but I've ruled these out by testing on a coworker's computer without them.

Comment: Is the script wrapped in a 'task :whatever_task => :environment do ' block?

Comment: do you know the user it is running under? rvm will allow you to specify a default ruby as well as you can add to the bash profile to pick the specific ruby for the user.

Comment: I think task is a rake thing, not a thor thing, @bkunzi01.

Comment: @engineersmnky it's running in my user account and rvm's default ruby is 2.3.1.